# Undeclared selector goBack warning and unrecognized selector sent to instance termination

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have been reading lots of similar questions and answers but still don't quite understand what's going wrong here.

I'm trying to create a button to go back to the previous view but I keep getting the errors mentioned in the title. Could someone advise me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listbutton.png"];
UIButton *listbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
listbutton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );
[listbutton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[listbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listbutton];
```

goBack:

```
- (void)goBack
{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

error:

> 2014-01-05 22:03:13.344 tablepractice[12509:70b]
>   -[DetailViewController goBack:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b72130 2014-01-05 22:03:13.348 tablepractice[12509:70b]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController
>   goBack:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b72130'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x017405e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x014c38b6 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x017dd903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x0173090b __*forwarding*** + 1019
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x017304ee
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d5874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77  6 
>   UIKit                               0x002330c2 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108   7   UIKit
>   0x0023304e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] +
>   61    8   UIKit                               0x0032b0c1 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66     9   UIKit
>   0x0032b484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577    10 
>   UIKit                               0x0032a733 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641    11  UIKit
>   0x0027051d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852    12  UIKit
>   0x00271184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232  13  UIKit
>   0x00244e86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242  14  UIKit
>   0x0022f18f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421     15  CoreFoundation 
>   0x016c983f **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 15  16  CoreFoundation                      0x016c91cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235  17  CoreFoundation                      0x016e629e __CFRunLoopRun + 910     18  CoreFoundation
>   0x016e5ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467     19  CoreFoundation
>   0x016e58db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   20  GraphicsServices
>   0x036e59e2 GSEventRunModal + 192  21  GraphicsServices
>   0x036e5809 GSEventRun + 104   22  UIKit
>   0x00231d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225   23  tablepractice
>   0x0000388d main + 141     24  libdyld.dylib
>   0x01d7e70d start + 1  25  ???
>   0x00000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

Comment: You need to include the exact and complete error message in your question. And show your `goBack:` method.

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[listbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This needs to be changed to not use a colon in the selector method:

```
[listbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

A colon implies that there is a parameter and your goBack method has no parameters.

Comment: Or the selector can be left as-is and the method can be updated to take the sender parameter.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was afraid it was something simple, but at least it's easy to fix :)